# Laravel using filter and map instead of foreach

Tags: php, laravel, dictionary, foreach, filter

I have two models, `Plan` and `Transactions`. Each `Plan` can have many `Transactions`. I want to get the total amount of all transactions related to all plans. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
    $plans = $this->plan->with('transactions')->get();

    $total = [];

    foreach($plans as $plan)
    {
        foreach($plan->transactions as $transaction)
        {
            $total[] = $transaction->amount;
        }
    }

    dd(array_sum($total)); // Works, I get the total amount of all transactions that are related to a Plan.
```

But I want to get rid of the foreach loops and use `filter` and/or `map` instead. I have tried the following:

```
    $test = $plans->filter(function ($plan) {
        return $plan->has('transactions');
    })->map(function ($plan) {
        return $plan->transactions;
    })->map(function ($transaction) {
        return $transaction; // Not sure what to do here, $transaction->amount doesn't work
    });
```

I'm sorta getting stuck in this last bit, where I end up with a collection of collections. Any ideas of how to accomplish this, at least without using the foreach loops? Perhaps maybe in the query itself?

So what I have is a few `Plans`, and each `Plan` can have many `Transactions`. Each `Transaction` has an `amount` field, in which I store the amount for each `Transaction`. I want to get the TOTAL AMOUNT for ALL transactions which are related to a Plan. So, the sum of the transactions.amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you already have a plan, the transactions property on that plan will be a collection, so you can use the `sum()` method on that:

```
$total = $plan->transactions->sum('amount');
```

Since it's just one specific plan, it doesn't matter whether you eager load it or not. But if it hasn't been loaded already, you can just do it through the database instead:

```
$total = $plan->transactions()->sum('amount');
```

---

If you have a collection of plans, use `reduce()`:

```
$total = $plans->reduce(function ($carry, $plan) {
    return $carry + $plan->transactions->sum('amount');
}, 0);
```

In this case, you do want to eager load the transactions to reduce the number of queries. (Otherwise, please refer to the above on going through the database instead.)

---

If you're coming from a query, you can either use joins or double queries - the latter is generally simpler:

```
$ids = Plan::where('condition')->pluck('id')->all();
$total = Transaction::whereIn('plan_id', $ids)->sum('amount');
```

---

And, of course, if you just want the total amount no matter what, there's no need to go through the plans at all. :)

```
$total = Transaction::sum('amount');
```

Comment: Seems to me that the `reduce` bit did the trick. @Alexey Mezenin, my Plans and Transactions are related using  Many-to-Many Polymorphic relation, so my Transactions do not have a `plan_id`, forgot to mention. Thanks @Joel Hinz and thanks @Alexey Mezenin for the help :)

Comment: And I wanted to point out, great answer here from @Joel Hinz, thanks for the explanations and the examples, really appreciate it

Comment: No sweat, glad it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have plan ID, you can use `sum()` method:

```
$this->transaction->where('plan_id', $planId)->sum('amount');
```

To count amount for all transactions, remove `where()` part.

To count amount for multiple plans, use `whereIn()` intsead of `where()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with this I am getting the total amount of transactions, and not the total amount of `amount` for each transaction. Maybe I explained it wrong in my OP or I'm misunderstanding your answer :) - I will update my OP

Comment: I think you misunderstand - he doesn't want the number of transactions, he wants to sum a field on the transactions table based on the plans.

Comment: That's exactly not what I want to do :P I want to get the total of the `amount` field for each transaction. I do not want to simply count how many rows are returned so to speak :) Edit, and thank you @Joel Hinz for explaining it, makes more sense like that, apologiesfor not explaining it right myself

Comment: @RonBrouwers thanks for updating the question. If you just want to count the sum of `amount` column for all transactions by specified plan(s), you can use `sum()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Alexey Mezenin, this solution would work if I had a one-to-many relation, but unfortunately I'm using a many-to-many polymorphic relation, since I've got loads of other models related to transactions as well.

Comment: @RonBrouwers you wrote 'Plan can have many Transactions' which usually means `hasMany()` relation. For other relation use `->relationName()` way. JFYI, this solution will create 2, 3 or 4 queries (depends on the relation type). For `hasMany()` my code would create just one simple and fast query.